# How can I get shared link with Google Drive Api in PHP

Tags: php, api, google-cloud-platform, drive

I am using google drive api with php. I do upload a file in new created folder. But i don't know "How can i get shared url for new folder". or "How can i give 'reader' permission for new email adress"?

I want to share folder. Not file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $service->files->create(
    $file,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
    )
);
```

File Id: `$fileId = $result['id'];`